# When before starts wamp server comming this issue [wamp server 3.2.9 version]

Tags: mysql, apache, wampserver, wamp64

[image]

When I am starting WAMP server, this error message was displayed. I tried to find out the issue but, I could not. if someone know the issue please help me.

Comment: What does the configuration file say on line 29?

Comment: Uninstall and then check the requirements before installing again. Make sure you have all the MSVC Runtime libraries BEFORE installing. See [here for all the runtimes libraries](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/vcpackages/all_vc_redist_x86_x64.zip)